# Stream Analytics Job shows no output in Power BI

Tags: azure, powerbi

When I start my Azure Stream Analytics job I don't see any results in my Power BI. After stopping and starting it I see it pop up at seemingly a random moment. Is there a reason for this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it takes a couple of minutes (have seen this max out at 15 min) before the output is generated.

In case you did the restart too quickly it might seem to be a random moment. Try to start it once and then wait a couple of minutes. Under the hood resources need to be provisioned, that can take some time.